# How to access framebuffer with FFMPEG?

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg

I'm writing an application which need to capture screen. I've looked up for solution and internet says that `FFMPEG` could do it. But I can't find the way to do that **IN CODE**. `FFMPEG` documentation seems to be very poor.

Can anybody please tell me how do I access framebuffer raw data with `FFMPEG`?

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg supports input of rawframes throught stdin:

With the arg `-f rawvideo` ffmpeg will expect frames coming from stdin

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt uyvy422 -s 1280x720 -i - -threads 0 -preset fast -y -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

You can check this [link](http://blog.mmacklin.com/2013/06/11/real-time-video-capture-with-ffmpeg/), it has useful information.

In Qt, you would run a [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) with ffmpeg with `-f rawvideo` and write to stdin with [write()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) method.

This is roughly how to acomplish it:

```
QProcess* process;

process->start("ffmpeg.exe", args, QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadWrite);
process->waitForStarted();

  ...

process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
videoFrame->GetBytes(&buffer);
process->write(buffer);
```

Comment: Can I by any chance do that by not starting a process? I've downloaded ffmpeg-3.4.1-win32-dev but I can't find which functions should I use

Comment: There is also a Qt wrapper for ffmpeg [here](https://github.com/scribblemaniac/qtffmpegwrapper) but it uses now deprecated methods, you either have to use an old version of ffmpeg or fix some methods and defines in the code.